# Twitter4j TwitterStream Stop/Close

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I have an Android app that starts a `TwitterStream` with Twitter4j and I am looking for help as to how to stop/close it if I do not need the stream anymore.  I start the stream on a preference change but would need to stop it in other parts of my app based on user actions.

Here is how I start the stream, which is the typical way I have found in documentation:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

cb.setDebugEnabled(true);

cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(A);

cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(B);

cb.setOAuthAccessToken(C);

cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(D));

TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice arg0) {

    }
    .
    .   
    .

};
FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
fq.follow(new long[]{X});

twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can stop the stream by following commands:

```
twitterStream.cleanUp(); // shutdown internal stream consuming thread
twitterStream.shutdown(); // Shuts down internal dispatcher thread shared by all TwitterStream instances.
```

you can check the api from the following link to learn the details of the api.
http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html

Comment: Could you help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471043/twitter-stream-api-to-get-users-tweets